# Associated type with bound is not being enforced when used as function parameter

Tags: rust

In the following example code the trait `Foo` requires that the associated type `X` implement the `Clone` trait.

When using the `impl Foo<X = Baz>` syntax in the `do_it` function signature, `cargo check` does not complain that `Baz` does not implement the `Clone` trait.

However, `cargo check` does complain about this issue, in the `impl Foo for Bar` block.

I would have expected `impl Foo<X = Baz>` to complain in the same way.

```rs
trait Foo {
    type X: Clone;
}

struct Bar;

struct Baz;

impl Foo for Bar {
    type X = Baz; // <- complains Baz does not impl Clone trait
}

fn do_it(foo: impl Foo<X = Baz>) {} // <- does not complain
```

This is not the case if `X` is a generic parameter. In that case, `cargo check` indicates that the `Clone` trait bound is not satisfied by `foo: impl Foo<Bar>`

```rs
trait Foo<X>
where
    X: Clone,
{
}

struct Bar;

struct Baz;

fn do_it(foo: impl Foo<Baz>) {} // <- complains Baz does not impl Clone trait
```

Is this intended behavior and if so why?

Comment: I don't think that's the intended behavior (I think it's just a bug), but it's not *that* much of an issue since you will just never be able to build a value which implements `Foo<X=Baz>` anyway.

Comment: There are a number of cases where some error messages will be inhibited by other, more siginficant error messages. For example, syntax errors inhibit type errors, type errors inhibit mutability errors, etc. This seems very similar to that, so as long as it doesn't accept an invalid program or reject a valid one, and the error messages that it shows are correct (even if others are inhibited), I don't think it's really a bug either (though perhaps an opportunity for improvement in the compiler diagnostics).

Comment: @Frxstrem This is not the case, as [it is compiling without errors if you remove the impl](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1b89438978e58efb832c5ff0e1c1fff3).

Comment: @jthulhu Even if it's unintended behavior, it's very unlikely to ever get fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in [the RFC introducing associated types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0195-associated-items.md#trait-bodies-defining-associated-items), in a short sentence:

> The `BOUNDS` and `WHERE_CLAUSE` on associated types are *obligations* for the implementor of the trait, and *assumptions* for users of the trait:
>
> ```rust
> trait Graph {
>     type N: Show + Hash;
>     type E: Show + Hash;
>     ...
> }
>
> impl Graph for MyGraph {
>     // Both MyNode and MyEdge must implement Show and Hash
>     type N = MyNode;
>     type E = MyEdge;
>     ...
> }
>
> fn print_nodes<G: Graph>(g: &G) {
>     // here, can assume G::N implements Show
>     ...
> }
> ```

What this means is that the person that is responsible to prove that the bounds hold is not the user of the trait (`do_it()` in your example) but the implementor of the trait. This is in contrast to generic parameters of traits, where the proof obligation is on the user.

The difference should be obvious when you look at it: with generic parameters, the types are foreign and unknown inside the trait implementation, so it must assume the bounds hole. The user of the trait, on the other hand, has concrete types for them (even if they're themselves generic, they're still concrete types from the point of view of the trait) and so it should prove the bounds hold. In contrast, with associated types the story is different: the implementor knows the concrete type, while the user assumes a generic type (even if, like in your code, it constrains them to a specific type, in the general case it is still unknown).

Note that with *where bounds* on associated types (`type Foo where Self::Foo: Clone`), that were introduced with generic associated types (yes, I know the RFC I linked bring them, but as far as I know they were not implemented and eventually implemented as part of GATs with different semantics), the story is again different from normal associated type bounds: the user has to prove them too (I think the both need to prove, but I'm not sure). This is because they're expected to be used for generic parameters on associated types, so they're similar to generic parameters on traits, or where clauses in them.